# Vector equation

Tags: equation-solving, vector, code-request

Is there any way to solve below equation in Mathematica?
I want to find vector 'X' as a function of vectors: A,V, and constants: b, e and d.
All vectors are 1 by 3.
 Equation is:

```
A + b V X.X + X (d V.X + 1 + e X.X) == 0
```

Which 0 in right-hand side is a 3 component vector. It is not a linear equation.
   The code I used is as below:

```
A = {a1, a2, a3};
v = {v1, v2, v3};
x = {x1, x2, x3};
Solve[-A.A + (-2 n - v.v ) (c + b x.x) + x.x (e f x.x + d v.x)^2 == 
 0, x, Real]
```

Comment: What is `X^2`? Square brackets have a special meaning in *Mathematica*; please replace them with parentheses if that is what you meant by them.

Comment: If `A` is a vector, then the right-hand side should also be a vector.

Comment: It is. A, V, X and zero are vectors. Could you help me to find the answer?

Comment: @Jens - I think it is clear from the OP's previous versions of this question that they have not used *Mathematica* before and do not understand the syntax necessary to encode a zero-vector.

Comment: It seems that you have understand the syntax and you have worked  with mathematica, so please answer the question. If not, please don't waste the time

Comment: @ Myridium Yes, it is clear. However, I am also interested in answering an analogous (more complex) question, to which this one can serve a first step. I would post it, if I thought the answer exists at all. The question is: "Is it possible to perform symbolic operations with vectors and tensors, if the latter are only fixed as symbols, as in the OP question". I will be more precise, if the answer to this question will appear. So, guys, can we reformulate the OP question such that it has sense, and can we answer this corrected question, if the answer exists at all?

Comment: @saranj - I have no interest in answering the question, but since you ask, I will help you to improve it. Please have a go at a few things (maybe look at `Solve` in the Documentation Center of *Mathematica*) and tell us what you've tried and what has failed. I think the reason that your question is not garnering positive attention is that it *appears* (whether true or not) that you have put no effort into learning the basics of *Mathematica* first or trying to solve the problem yourself. It *appears* as though you are trying to get some copy-pasteable code in a way that is an abuse of the site

Comment: I have tried to solve it myself but I couldn't and I didn't put here my wrong code. but if you think it's better to put it, ok I do so.

Comment: @saranj - Yes, please do! That's what we want to see :)

Comment: I did. I hope it could help.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but too long for a comment. I can't manage to solve the question myself, but here are some things:

- In *Mathematica*, the three-component zero-vector is `{0,0,0}`. You should replace `0` with this.
- Unless otherwise specified, *Mathematica* will assume that symbols are complex numbers, not real vectors. What you should do is something like this:

  V = {v1, v2, v3};
  A = {a1, a2, a3};
  X = {x1, x2, x3};

Now when you type the expression `A + b V X.X + X (d V.X + 1 + e X.X)` and evaluate it, you will see that *Mathematica* recognises it as a three-component vector:

```
 {a1 + b v1 (x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2) + 
  x1 (1 + d (v1 x1 + v2 x2 + v3 x3) + e (x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2)), 

 a2 + b v2 (x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2) + 
  x2 (1 + d (v1 x1 + v2 x2 + v3 x3) + e (x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2)), 

 a3 + b v3 (x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2) + 
  x3 (1 + d (v1 x1 + v2 x2 + v3 x3) + e (x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2))}
```

Remember: each of these symbols will be assumed by *Mathematica* to be a scalar, and that's what we want.

- To stop *Mathematica* giving you complex solutions and to speed up the solving, you should specify that you want to solve over the *Reals*:

  Solve[ X^2 (d V.X + e f X^2)^2 - (a^2 + V^2 (b X^2 + c) + 2 a.V (b X^2 + c)) == {0,0,0}, X, Reals]

Note that solving for `X` here happens to work because `X` evaluates to `{x1,x2,x3}` which is the list of variables to solve for. (See the documentation for `Solve`)

Unfortunately, even after this syntax is all corrected, *Mathematica* seems to have trouble solving this equation. Hopefully someone else can help with that.

Comment: Thank you. I made my code better. I put the new code in question. The new problem is, when I use Reals, it doesn't work! :( Do you know where is the problem?